# Clip HTML element without reflow

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to clip the content of an HTML element in an animation, but without triggering reflows. Anyone know if it's possible? Take this example ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hy01n6ko/)):

```
<div>
    This is a div<br>
    With some content<br>
    Moar moar moar<br>
    Yolo<br>
    C'est ca
</div>
```

With the following CSS:

```
div {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: height 0.4s linear;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
}

div.hide {
    height: 0;
}
```

And this JavaScript:

```
setInterval(function() {
    document.querySelector('div').classList.toggle('hide');
}, 1000);
```

Clips the content through an animation but reflows like crazy and gives a janky animation on mobile. I can achieve a similar result with `transform: scaleY(0)` ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hqck2m60/1/)), but that doesn't do clipping thus giving a different visual effect.

Comment: Saw your solution with clip(): I learned yesterday that it was [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#clip-property) (but must be supported so no problem) and that [clip-path](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) existed. Support for HTML elements and SVG is way better than what MDN says though it may not be sufficient yet (didn't test yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, managed to fix it using [clip](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip).

```
div {
    transition: clip 0.4s linear;
    height: 300px;
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    left: 40px;
    clip: rect(0, 100vw, 300px, 0);
}

div.hide {
    clip: rect(0, 100vw, 0, 0);
}
```